# OAuth2.0 through command line in Rust

Tags: rust, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to make an app that uses OAuth2.0, and I currently have it working in a roundabout way that I don't quite like. I manage to create the link needed for the authentication, and the `open` crate will open it, for a user to press "allow". The user would then need to copy the link and paste it back into the command line.
I don't like this solution, is there another way to authenticate without being sent to browser? Is there a way to redirect to my Rust command line (not ideal but slightly better).
For more info, here are the API docs: https://myanimelist.net/apiconfig/references/authorization
As well as my current code:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fs::File, io::Write};

use reqwest::Body;
use serde_json::Value;
use url::Url;

use super::{CLIENT_ID, TOKEN};

pub async fn login() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Creates and sends the url
    let code_verify = pkce::code_verifier(50);
    let code_challenge = pkce::code_challenge(&code_verify);
    open::that(&format!("https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={}&code_challenge={code_challenge}", CLIENT_ID.clone()))?;

    // Receives the authorization url
    println!("Once you've authenticated, enter the redirected URL:");
    let mut input = String::new();
    std::io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    // Parses url for code
    let url = Url::parse(input.trim()).unwrap();
    let code = url
        .query_pairs()
        .find(|(param, _)| param == "code")
        .map(|(_, value)| value.into_owned())
        .expect("Failed to extract authorization code");

    // Requests the access_token
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let res = client
        .post("https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/token")
        .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .body(Body::from(format!(
            "client_id={}&code={}&code_verifier={}&grant_type=authorization_code",
            CLIENT_ID.clone(),
            code,
            code_challenge
        )))
        .send()
        .await?;
    let json: Value = res.json().await?;

    // Saves token to a file and globally
    let mut token = TOKEN.lock().unwrap();
    *token = json["access_token"].as_str().unwrap_or("").to_string();

    // Saves code to file
    let mut file = File::create("token.txt")?;
    file.write_all(&*token.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's not my ideal, because I don't believe I can disable browser confirmation, but here's code to redirect back to my Rust terminal app. To put into words beforehard, I used the crate `tiny_http` to create a localhost server, and made the API redirect to `http://localhost:8080/auth`. I then created a loop that would wait until it finds a request at that link, and I parsed the code out of it. Here's my code, do note, I intend to parse the URL better later:

```
use std::{error::Error, fs::File, io::Write, sync::Arc};
use reqwest::Body;
use serde_json::Value;
use url::Url;
use tiny_http::{Response, Server};
use super::{CLIENT_ID, TOKEN};

pub async fn login() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Creates and sends the url
    let code_verify = pkce::code_verifier(50);
    let code_challenge = pkce::code_challenge(&code_verify);
    let auth_url: String = format!("https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={}&code_challenge={code_challenge}", CLIENT_ID.clone());
    // open::that(&auth_url)?; //opens link automatically

    // Opens a localhost server
    let server = Server::http("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    println!("Please visit: {}", auth_url);
    // Wait for the callback with the authorization code
    let mut code = String::new();
    // TODO: do this better
    for request in server.incoming_requests() {
        // request should look like `localhost:8080/auth?code=...`, splits '/auth' and 'code=...'
        if let Some(query) = request.url().split_once("?") {
            if let Some(data) = query.1.split_once("=") {
                // println!("{}", data.1);
                code = data.1.to_string();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Requests the access_token
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let res = client.post("https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/token")
        .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .body(Body::from(format!(
            "client_id={}&code={}&code_verifier={}&grant_type=authorization_code",
            CLIENT_ID.clone(),
            code,
            code_challenge
        )))
        .send()
        .await?;
    let json: Value = res.json().await?;

    // Saves token to a file and globally
    let mut token = TOKEN.lock().unwrap();
    *token = json["access_token"].as_str().unwrap_or("").to_string();

    // Saves code to file
    let mut file = File::create("token.txt")?;
    file.write_all(&*token.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}

fn handle_authorization(server: Arc<Server>) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    for request in server.incoming_requests() {
        let url = match Url::parse(&format!("http://localhost{}", request.url())) {
            Ok(url) => url,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        if let Some(code) = url.query_pairs().find(|(param, _)| param == "code") {
            let response = Response::from_string("Authorization successful! You can close this window.");
            request.respond(response)?;
            return Ok(code.1.into_owned());
        }
    }

    Err("Failed to retrieve authorization code".into())
}
```